# C++ Lambdas: captured pointer to STL container changing address after pop?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to figure out why the following code breaks. After `objects->pop();` is called in the lambda expression, the memory address of `objects` changes to 0xfeeefeee when debugging in Visual Studio. I can get around this issue by doing `auto p = objects;` before the pop, and then using `p` instead of `objects` in the second line of the lambda. However, I must be missing something fundamental here.

```
class Obj
{
public:
    Obj(stack<shared_ptr<Obj>>* const objects) {
        fun = [=] {
            objects->pop(); // objects' address changed after this executes
            objects->push(shared_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(objects)));
        };
    }

    function<void(void)> fun;
};

int main()
{
    stack<shared_ptr<Obj>> objects;
    objects.push(shared_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(&objects)));
    objects.top().get()->fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I instinctively feel that there must be some [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in there somewhere. It just... looks wrong!

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: `objects->push(shared_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(objects)));`
Why are you passing `objects` as parameter when the call to `push()` is via `objects` itself? That doesn't seem like a good design to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are observing is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The memory that the captured `objects` variable occupies is freed when you call `objects->pop();` A good hint for this is the value it changes to: [`0xFEEEFEEE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/2700399). This magic number indicates freed memory.

Let's analyse what happens.

```
stack<shared_ptr<Obj>> objects;
objects.push(shared_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(&objects)));
```

A `stack` with `shared_ptr`'s is created. Pushed on top of it is a new `Obj` instance, whose constructor argument is a pointer to our `stack`.

```
Obj(stack<shared_ptr<Obj>>* const objects) {
    fun = [=] { 
       /* ... */
    };
}
```

A `function` object is assigned a lambda, which captures the `objects` argument.

`objects.top().get()->fun();` calls the function object:

```
objects->pop(); // objects' address changed after this executes
```

The top element of the stack that `objects` points to, is the `Obj` instance to which the `fun` object belongs. By popping it off, the only (and therefore last) instance of the `shared_ptr` holding a reference to it goes out of scope and frees the memory that it used. This includes the captured pointer to `objects`. In a debug build `HeapFree` sets it to `0xFEEEFEEE`. In a release build anything could happen. After this point you're referencing released memory, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: `The line objects.push(shared_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(&objects))); creates an std::shared_ptr pointing to the automatic variable objects.` What? No, it doesn't...

Comment: To elaborate on what Lightness said, `shared_ptr<Obj>(new Obj(&objects))` creates a perfectly fine shared pointer to a new instance of class `Obj`, which happens to get a pointer to a local variable as a parameter to its constructor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I totally analysed that wrong. The answer is updated.

Comment: This makes complete sense, thanks! To others: the example code here contrived to keep it short.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `objeccts->pop()`, the `shared_ptr` on top of the stack is destroyed. It is the last pointer to your instance of `Obj`, so that instance is destroyed. That instance contains the function object `fun`, so the function object is also destroyed.

Any access to the captured variables of the function object after this point is undefined behaviour, which first happens right on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

For what I could deduce debugging your code, it seems to me that eventually you are doing `pop` on the top of stack, and with that you are trying to `delete` the pointer to the `objects` (the variable in the `main` function: by the way, you should rename that to eliminate confusion). As it is not on the heap, UB kicks in, and it gives (me) a segmentation fault.